# c++ - error :invalid initialization of reference of type 'const testGetter*&' from expression of type 'testGetter* const'

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, mingw

I know it has come up a zillion times but this time it was autogenerated code :

```
class testGetter{
    testGetter * ptr; // wrote this
public:
// this is autogenerated by eclipse
    const testGetter*& getPtr() const {
        return ptr;
    }

    void setPtr(const testGetter*& ptr) {
        this->ptr = ptr;
    }
};
```

I am on windows 7 mingw - g++ version ***4.7.0***

So is it a bug in the templates of eclipse (juno) ?

EDIT : compiler invocation :

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fpermissive -o Visitor.o "..\\Visitor.cpp"
```

**EDIT 2013.06.12** : I should have added that [I reported the thing](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393297) after the feedback I got here

Comment: What's wrong with it exactly? And what data did it use to autogenerate such code?

Comment: It looks like a bug: I'm not sure why the `&`s have been put in, or why the argument for `setPtr` is declared `const`. Is this from a project template?

Comment: The problem is the misplaced "const" of the getter. As it is written, it returns a reference to a pointer to a constant testGetter. It should be `testGetter * const & getPtr()` - a reference to a constant pointer to testGetter.

Comment: I wrote `class testGetter{
    testGetter * ptr;}` and then hit source > generate getters and setters. So it generated `getPtr()` and `setPtr()` and when I build  I got the error in the title. I suspect it is a 4.7 thing.

Comment: @MadScientist: hmm thanks - so it is a bug in eclipse ? Gosh

Comment: I never regretted switching my coding style to `T const &` instead of `const T &`. That way you can read the type from right to left (reference to a const T) and you have not problems seeing the difference between `T const *` (pointer to a const T), `T * const` (const pointer to a (mutable) T), and `T const * const` (const pointer to a const T).

Comment: @MadScientist : thanks - but the problem is a compiler error - could you provide some insight on it ? Have you got eclipse installed ? What I want to know is if eclipse generates the wrong code - and if this has anything to do with g++ 4.7 on mingw

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Eclipse generates incorrect code. I have provided an answer explaining why that code is not allowed in the language. C++ is quite a complex language, and I would not trust code generation in general. It will work for simple cases, but when things get complicated it is hard to get it right. Use code generation with a pinch of salt, understanding that it takes the burden of typing away, but in some cases you will need to fix the output. Also consider that getters are not usually a good idea, and less so of pointers. Consider whether semantically it makes sense to return a pointer.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Also note that the problem is not just the particular tool, but the process of automation. What should the getter in your class do? Is the value of the pointed object part of the state? In that case you need to return a `testGetter const * const &`, but in some cases it isn't (`std::shared_ptr`) and you want to return a plain `testGetter *` directly. The decision is to be taken with the design of the program in mind, and Eclipse (or any other tool) cannot possibly know what your design requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const testGetter*&
```

That represents a reference to a non-const pointer to a const `testGetter`. You cannot convert from a `testGetter*` to that type as that would break const-correctness in the following example:

```
const testGetter tmp;
testGetter t;
t.getPtr() = &tmp;     // !!!
```

If the conversion was allowed the above code would compile, and after the line marked with the !!! the pointer stored inside `t` (which is of type `testGetter*`) would be pointing to a `const testGetter`, breaking const-correctness in the code.

You probably want to return just a pointer, not a reference to a pointer:

```
const testGetter* getPtr() const
```

Or alternatively add an extra `const` to guarantee const-correctness:

```
const testGetter *const& getPtr() const
```

In either case, the code is ensuring that you don't set the internal `testGetter*` to point to a `const testGetter`.

If the getter was autogenerated by the tool (Eclipse), then the tool has a bug or is a bit too simplistic to generate correct code. You will need to either create the getter manually or else fix the output of the generator.

---

Sidenote: Given a choice of Eclipse CDT or g++, I'd bet that the bug is in eclipse more often than not.

Comment: Thanks ! I work with java lately & all those * blink a lot :D